# Apply failed: Couldn't copy file "C:\Program Files\IDA Pro 8.0\python\3\PyQt5\python_3.9\sip.pyd

Tags: reverse-engineering, python-3.8, ida

When I run idapyswitch.exe, I encounter this information

```
Checking installs from "Python Software Foundation"
Checking "Python 3.10 (64-bit)" (3.10)
Found: "C:\Program Files\Python310\" (version: 3.10.5 ('3.10.5150.1013'))
Checking "Python 3.9 (64-bit)" (3.9)
Found: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\" (version: 3.9.7 ('3.9.7150.1013'))
Checking "Python 3.10" (3.10)
Found: "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0" (version: 3.10.10 ('3.10.10150.1013'))
Ignoring unusable AppStore Python "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.dll"
IDA previously used: "C:\Program Files\Python310\python310.dll" (guessed version: 3.10.5 ('3.10.5150.1013')). Making this the preferred version.
The following Python installations were found:
    #0: 3.10.5 ('3.10.5150.1013') (C:\Program Files\Python310\python3.dll)
    #1: 3.9.7 ('3.9.7150.1013') (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\python3.dll)
Please pick a number between 0 and 1 (default: 0)
1
Applying version 3.9.7 ('3.9.7150.1013')`
```

and it said permission denied

```
Apply failed: Couldn't copy file "C:\Program Files\IDA Pro 8.0\python\3\PyQt5\python_3.9\sip.pyd" to "C:\Program Files\IDA Pro 8.0\python\3\PyQt5\sip.pyd": Permission denied
```

I'm using IDA 8.0 and Python 3.10.10

I have pick number 0 and it still prompt the same error. How can i fix this

Comment: Have you executed idaswitch from a command line that has admin permissions? Modifications to files in the program files folder require admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answers to this very problem and realized that I was running idapyswitch *while IDA was running.*

Closed IDA, re-ran idapyswitch, no errors.

This happens because of a '[File Sharing Violation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/the-case-of-the-mysterious-locked-file/ba-p/723349#:%7E:text=This%20error%20results%20when%20a,combination%20of%20those%20access%20types.).'